# installing swig i had to untar something using msys, but it doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, msys

i installed MinGW and MSYS required to install swig.
using msys terminal it asked me to download pcre-8.36.tar.bz2 form pcre site, and asked me to: "Build PCRE as a static library using the Tools/pcre-build.sh script"
so...

$ Tools/pcre-build.sh

Looking for PCRE tarball...

Extracting tarball: pcre-8.36.tar.bz2

tar: This does not look like a tar archive

tar: Skipping to next header

tar: 378 garbage bytes ignored at end of archive

tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Could not untar pcre-8.36.tar.bz2

but it doesn' t work, i am on windows XP, i tried using pcre-8.36.tar.gz, i can unzip as usual but in this case i need this way to proceed in the installation...

Comment: Have you attempted to re-download the file and verify it?

Comment: i re-download pcre-8.36.tar.bz2 but it doesn' t even work, i think the problem is something missing on my computer... 
i tryed download also pcre-8.36.tar.gz (i don't know the difference) but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I have used this workaround:

- retrieve the .tar file with 7Zip, and
- put it in the /usr/src/swig directory (as described in the instructions: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Windows.html#Windows_cygwin_mingw)